# Change contrast, brightness, saturation, or color of UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I'm looking for a good way to modify some elements of `UIImage` like brightness, contrast, saturation (for colored images), and colors (colorize).

For now I use per pixel operations but it's not very fast.
For each pixel in the image, I modify the color data for contrast, brightness etc. I use some sources from [UIImageAdjust](https://github.com/coryleach/UIImageAdjust) for brightness and contrast.

I'm looking for a more effective way to like blending the images with color (a faster way, but i can get what i want with CGBlendMode).

Any ideas ?

Comment: this lib might point you in the right direction! [http://www.cocoabyss.com/uikit/introducing-nyximagesutilities-ios/](http://cocoaintheshell.com/2012/01/nyximagesutilities-nyximageskit/)

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at Apple's demo app [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html), it's really fast:

[image]
[image]

Comment: like i say i test GLImageProcessing but i the exemple you can't use brightness and contrast and saturation :)

Comment: Hmm I don't know if it's that difficult to combine the separate image processors.

Comment: Don't bother with the GLImageProcessing, I managed to modify the code to combine the filters the way that it doesn't lose the previous filter when you switch back and forth.
But it only works on small images when I tried to apply it on the photos taken by the device camera, iPhone graphic card doesn't allow as the loading texture is limited to 2048 but photos have a dimension of 2592, so a lot of time wasted.